# Facebook Like Button Signed in as Page

Tags: facebook, styles, facebook-like, facebook-page

We are using the facebook like button for our university social media page, but when someone is signed in as a page it displays a large photo with a red background, an even larger white background, with text "switch." We were wondering if there was a way we could change the format or if there is anything being done on facebook's end to add more versatility so that we could:

1. remove the white background so that it doesn't conflict when it is on a grey background,
2. offer options, so when users are signed in as a page, it can either be displayed as the current format, or one that is more the size of the like button, when users are signed in as themselves, so that it doesn't break the design of the webpage.
3. Offer other options for colors, instead of only red, so that it can blend with your color scheme and look aesthetically pleasing.
4. Have an option to choose what text to display instead of "Switch," which may not be intuitive.

Answer (score 2):

First off, welcome to the club. So many of us feel your pain. Unfortunately, you're stuck in a bit of a rut.

The Facebook 'Like' button is displayed in an iFrame on your page - which means that Facebook controls the content that's displayed there and the CSS that styles it. Because you can't use CSS from your site to style an iFrame from a separate domain, there's no good way to control the button's styling on your site. So that effectively knocks out option 1, 3, & 4.

As for option 2, that might be your best bet...

The 'Switch' button from Facebook is always the same size - which means it's a big square, as opposed to the smaller one-line button that some people use (I assume that's the one you're using, right?). Normally, we fix any layout issues by styling the iFrame to `overflow: hidden;` and with a set CSS `height` (if you're using the 1-line buttons, it's generally 32px). This will cut off the red 'Switch' button, which looks ugly...but at least it will allow you to maintain the same page layout, without the mis-sized button throwing off your page elements.

Ultimately, the iframe situation gives Facebook a lot of control to make their 'Like' buttons uniform on all sites - which is pretty cool. Unfortunately, when something looks bad, you don't have a lot of options to dynamically change it. Good luck!